# How can I merge two dataframes together with some conditional requirements?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`. I would like to join the two with the following conditions:

1. merge df1 and df2 on `gender` and `Test`
2. `TestDate` in `df1` need to be within `Date1` and `Date2` from `df2`
3. `all.x = TRUE` (keep df1 records)

How can I handle the second part?

[image]

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 5, 4), Gender = c("F", "M", "M", 
"F", "F"), TestDate = structure(c(17897, 17898, 18630, 18262, 
17900), class = "Date"), Test = c("Weight", "Weight", "ELA", 
"ELA", "Math")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


df2 <- structure(list(Test = c("Weight", "Weight", "ELA", "ELA", "ELA", 
"ELA", "Math", "Math"), Gender = c("F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", 
"F", "M"), Date1 = structure(c(17532, 17534, 17536, 17537, 18266, 
18267, 17897, 17539), class = "Date"), Ave = c(97, 99, 85, 84, 
83, 82, 88, 89), Date2 = structure(c(18993, 18995, 18266, 18267, 
18997, 18998, 18999, 19000), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
merge(x = df1, 
      y = df2) %>% 
  filter(TestDate %between% list(Date1, Date2))
```

Comment: The outcome is what I want. It is correct `merge` without defining `by` is the same as full join?

Comment: Yes, it will join on any matching column names (in this case Gender and Test). You can define them explicitely if you want, but it's not needed in this case

Comment: By default `merge` is an inner join, not a full join, the args `all`, `all.x`, `all.y` can change this

Answer (score 7):

Here is a [tidyverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidyverse) solution.

```r
library(tidyverse)

inner_join(df1, df2) %>%
  filter(TestDate >= Date1 & TestDate <= Date2)
#> Joining, by = c("Gender", "Test")
#> # A tibble: 5 x 7
#>      ID Gender TestDate   Test   Date1        Ave Date2
#>   <dbl> <chr>  <date>     <chr>  <date>     <dbl> <date>
#> 1     1 F      2019-01-01 Weight 2018-01-01    97 2022-01-01
#> 2     2 M      2019-01-02 Weight 2018-01-03    99 2022-01-03
#> 3     3 M      2021-01-03 ELA    2020-01-06    82 2022-01-06
#> 4     5 F      2020-01-01 ELA    2018-01-05    85 2020-01-05
#> 5     4 F      2019-01-04 Math   2019-01-01    88 2022-01-07
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org).</sup>

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks for the edit, I forgot to include the link.

Answer (score 7):

We may use non-equi join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[df1, on = .(Gender, Test,  Date1 <= TestDate,  Date2 >= TestDate)]
```

-output

```
   Test Gender      Date1   Ave      Date2    ID
   <char> <char>     <Date> <num>     <Date> <num>
1: Weight      F 2019-01-01    97 2019-01-01     1
2: Weight      M 2019-01-02    99 2019-01-02     2
3:    ELA      M 2021-01-03    82 2021-01-03     3
4:    ELA      F 2020-01-01    85 2020-01-01     5
5:   Math      F 2019-01-04    88 2019-01-04     4
```

Comment: Great answer! If I want to do with `data.table`, I saw sometimes people also use sth like `df2[df1, ,roll = T]`. Could you tell me what `[df1, ,roll = T]` really mean?

Comment: @Stataq thanks. If you check `?data.table`, the docs says `+Inf (or TRUE) rolls the prevailing value in x forward. It is also known as last observation carried forward (LOCF).`

Comment: Thanks so much! Very helpful as always. `data.table` provides some clever way to merge df. seldom use this but will try this rout more. :D

Answer (score 4):

If your condition #3 takes priority over condition #2, you may have to do a left join and check for missing value.

E.g., suppose we modify the last entry of `df1`:

```
df1[df1[,"ID"]==4, "Test"] <- "Chemistry"
df1
```

[image]

Then, if we want condition #3 to take priority over condition #2:

```
left_join(df1, df2, by = c("Test", "Gender")) %>%
    filter((TestDate >= Date1 & TestDate <= Date2) | is.na(Ave)) %>%
    select(-c(Date1, Date2))
```

[image]

Comment: Good catch! That is a situation that might happen.